# Datetime format conversion in apex

Tags: apex, datetime, html5

I have an input field in my visualforce page which uses the html 5 input element as `type="datetime-local"`. The value that I capture from the field is of the format `2016-04-09T23:58` . I want to use and save this field on to the database in salesforce and I cant assign the same value to the field directly. Even to parse salesforce expects a different format something like this `09/04/2016 5:10 PM`.

If I can do something like `Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('24/11/2011 1:46 PM')` then I can assign it to a field in Salesforce but there is nothing where I can use `2016-04-09T23:58` directly. I will have to convert `2016-04-09T23:58` to `09/04/2016 5:10 PM` and do it.

Is there any better way to achieve this  or am I missing something here

Comment: Allowed format for `DateTime` form is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` so in user input simply add `:00` as second value;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 : Thanks thats a good idea and works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed format for `DateTime` form is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` so in user input simply add `:00` as second value;

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `DateTime.newInstanceGmt(year, month, date, hour, minute, second)` method, as seen [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstanceGmt_3).

Or if your datetime string is in local time, you could also use the `Datetime.newInstance(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_newInstance_4).

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 : Thanks thats a good idea and works greate

Comment: @BobGali If that is the best answer, please select it by clicking the ✓ symbol.